# Build Ustream type application with TokBox API?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, opentok, tokbox

It's not immediately clear from their site, but can one build a one to many streaming app like Ustream using TokBox web/iOS APIs? Is it limited to just chat.

I'd want to make something that captures video from the desktop or ios device and makes that video accessible at some public URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is capable. OpenTok works with Publishers and Subscribers. A single Publisher can publish to a session then many users can subscribe to the publishers stream using a public access token.

Check out the [API](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/features) it shows what you can do with it, how it does it and even shows some good demos. There are many examples of how they have used it for online chat shows and other similar one-to-many applications.

They've also very recently released their WebRTC version which makes it definitely worth a look!